# click input on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to Javascript.

I'm trying to run a Javascript code that clicks a button on a web page. 
The HTML code looks like this:

```
<div class="felement fgroup" id="yui_3_17_2_2_1446895504264_827"><input name="savegrade" value="Save changes" type="submit" id="id_savegrade"> <input name="saveandshownext" value="Save and show next" type="submit" id="id_saveandshownext"> <input name="cancelbutton" value="Cancel" type="submit" onclick="skipClientValidation = true; return true;" class=" btn-cancel" id="id_cancelbutton"></div>
```

this element is called 'x'. I would like to click the submit button with 'id_saveandshownext' Id.

I have tried:

```
x.getElementsById('id_saveandshownext').click();
```

didn't work...
how do I click this button?

Comment: `getElementById()`, not `getElement` **s** `ById()` voting to close as Typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use document like this:

```
document.getElementById("id_saveandshownext").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are using jquery you can use  following -

```
<script> 
//your function that exectues button to be clicked
$(function(){
   $('#id_saveandshownext').click();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also trigger the click event like this:

```
document.getElementById("id_saveandshownext").trigger("click");
```